# jQuery plugin for vertical filter pills

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, e-commerce

Is there a working jQuery plugin which can show selected filter options from the horizontal filter col on top of product list as shown in the image.

[image: filter pills][image: vertical filter pills]

I need to display them like in the snippet from the image with working close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? (That's not a plugin, but just an example of how to create the elements)

```css
.FilterButtons{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.FilterBtn{
  margin: 0 7px;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px 0 0 9px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.FilterBtnCenter{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left; 

}
.FilterBtnLeft{
  float: left;
}
.FilterBtnRight{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-left:7px;
  padding-right:7px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="FilterButtons">
          
          <div class="FilterBtn">
            <a href="#"><div class="FilterBtnLeft"></div></a>
            <div class="FilterBtnCenter"> 10% - 20% <a href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="FilterBtnRight"> &#x274E; </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="FilterBtn">
            <a href="#"><div class="FilterBtnLeft"></div></a>
              <div class="FilterBtnCenter"> Round Neck <a href="#"></a></div>
              <div class="FilterBtnRight"> &#x274E; </div>
          </div>
          
         </div>
```